# S3 presigned url PUT and POST returning 200 but files not uploading in most cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using presigned URLs. Originally I tried PUT but swapped to POST to try and fix this issue however it seems to be the same in both cases.

Server code:
PUT

```
  const { fileName, fileType } = ctx.query

  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: 'eu-west-1'
  });
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: fileType
  };
  let url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params)
  return url
```

Client code: PUT

```
let put = await axios.put(url, file, {
  headers: { "Content-Type": file.type }
})
```

Server code: POST

```
  const postParams = {
    Expires: 60,
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
    Conditions: [
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
      ["content-length-range",  0, 1000000], // 0 - 1 MB
    ],
    Fields: {
        key: fileName
    }
  }

  const data = s3.createPresignedPost(postParams);
  return data
```

Client code: POST

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Content-Type", file.type);
Object.entries(data.fields).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  formData.append(k, v);
});
formData.append("file", file); // must be the last one

try {
  let response = await fetch(data.url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  });
  return response
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error uploading image")
  return new Error ("Image upload error")
}
```

S3 CORS Policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

As far as I can tell all headers and query parameters (PUT) formData (POST) seem correct, I am consistently getting 200 (PUT) 204 (POST) responses on all upload attempts. Only when I target a specific bucket does the upload work and even more strangely, I have to run the server that signs the URL locally. Once the signing server is deployed live the files uploaded (from the same locally deployed client) will not appear in the s3 bucket but the response will still be 200. If I try to upload to a different bucket I still receive status 200 but no file uploads even when the signing server is running locally.

If I put deliberate errors in the signing parameters or s3 bucket CORS policy I will get a 403 on upload.

Comment: Does the Lambda, which creates the `presignedUrl`, has enough permissions to `putObject` to this specific bucket?

Comment: What do you mean by "only when I target a specific bucket does the upload work"?

Comment: The IAM access keys used have S3 FullAccess permissions.

Comment: I have tested with multiple buckets, with one bucket the upload worked, but only when signed from a local server. The same bucket did not work when signed from prod server even though prd server is using exact same credentails. Other buckets all did not work.

Comment: And when I say did not work, they return a 200 OK status but the file never appears in S3.

Comment: add 'Content-Type': ' ' like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to leave comments yet, but I was curious if this question was still an issue for you?  If so, does CloudWatch show any error messages for the times the file fails to load into S3?  What file types get uploaded?

We have some working code for an API that uses PUT to upload a file to an S3 bucket.  The ContentType is always 'application/octet-stream' for us, and when I do Postman tests I have to manually add ContentType to the header for the PUT request that uses the signed url.

Here's the function that gets the signed url...

```
async getSignedDocumentUrl(s3Request) {
    this._logInfo('Controller.getSignedDocumentUrl()');
    this._logInfo(JSON.stringify(s3Request));
    const { bucketName, key } = s3Request;
    const { expires } = this.config.AWS.S3;
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key,
      Expires: expires,
      ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    };
    const url = await this.s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
    return url;
  }
```

I don't have client code to show you, but I have an integration test that uses the url to upload a file...  It only checks for the 200 status which you said you got too, but when I go to S3, I see the file there.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
...
  describe('Given I have a signed url', ()=>{
    describe('When I send a PUT request to the url with a file', ()=>{
      it('Then I should get a successful response', async ()=>{
        const hashedValue = getHashedValue();
        const fileName = 'test.pdf';
        const endpoint = getApiGatewayEndpoint(fileName);

        let signedUrl = '';
        await fetch(endpoint, {
          method: 'get',
          headers: {
            'x-custom': hashedValue // internal use only
          }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => {
            signedUrl = new URL(json.signedUrl);
          });

        const formData = new FormData();
        const content = 'test file';
        const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "pdf"});
        formData.append('test', blob);

        let uploadResponse = '';
        await fetch(signedUrl, {
          method: 'put',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
          },
          body: formData
        })
          .then(res => {
            uploadResponse = res.status;
          });
        expect(uploadResponse).toEqual(200);
      });
    });
  });
```

The bucket is blocked from public access and does not have a CORS policy defined.  The lambda's IAM role has write access to the bucket.  We only upload PDFs right now, but we do have different buckets for different environments and the same code still works.

Comment: add 'Content-Type': ' ' like this.